# Definite Integals Obtained From Approximations Using Chebyshev Polynomial

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Was trying to use chebyshev polynomial to obtain a cubic approximation to $f(x)=\frac{1}{x} $

I did it over the interval $[-1,1] $

Solving gave me the following four definite integrals:

$C_0=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$C_1=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$C_2=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{2x^2-1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$C_3=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{4x^3-3x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Now my problem is how to integrate these integrals analytically without resorting to numerical methods such as trapezoidal rule or Simpson rule.

Of course there's an exception: $C_1$ & $C_3$

Comment: Why would you try to approximate a function in this manner around a pole?

Comment: @RonGordon so the function cannot be approximated to a cubic polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

if you look closer you see that all of them are related to each other and that just $x = sin(\theta)$ solves them all.

Comment: I don't think using the substitution $x=\sin\theta$ would solve that of $C_2$ & $C_3$

Comment: $C_2 = $ (something) $+ C_0$. this something is easy to calculate (by the substitution $u = 1 - x^2$), and you should have $C_0$ using $x = \sin \theta$

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can show me the step-by-step workings on how to get $C_0$ & $C_2$